# Image compression, carrierwave and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

we're trying to compress the images we serve up on our site. We use carrierwave and asset_sync to serve our assets from S3 and Cloudfront.

The main issue we're now facing in terms of site performance is image compression. What is the best way of going about this? We've found a couple of compression tools (jpegoptim, pingcrush) that may work well - but we're not sure how to set these up on Heroku.

Right now, we are not compressing our images at all and we definitely want to fix that so any help on this front would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Ringo

Answer (score 0):

Well, Heroku supports python, java and lot of other languages. You need to first write an application which compresses the images to jpeg format and store them to s3 .Then if your images are one which are uploaded by the users, you might want to integrate this application with your site , and associate the link of the image in S3. If you are using cloudfront(which is recommended) then your link will be different from what you will see in the properties section of image. It should be easy once you develop an application to do compression and store in s3.